# JS variable access inside function impossible with .data() since jquery upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I have this portion of code which dates back to 2012 which was working

```
(function ( $ ) {
$.widget('MMB.MMBBrowser', {
    options: {
        'path': {
            'media_data': null,
            'category_data': null
        },
        'translation': {
            'items_found': 'item(s) found',
            'are_you_sure': 'Are you sure?',
            'media_browser': 'Media Browser',
            'items_selected': 'item(s) selected',
            'select': 'Select'
        },
    },
    'browser': function (event) {
        $this = $(this).data('MMBBrowser');
        // outputs null
        console.log($this);

        // error, calls options to undefined
        $this.options.translation.media_browser;


        return false;
    },
});
```

Since a global update (could be jquery, or the widget library), I got `Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`

How can I access to the `options.translation.media_browser` variable please ?

*EDIT: adding those console.log inside the browser function outputs:*

```
    console.log($(this).data('MMB.MMBBrowser')); // undefined
    console.log(this.options); // undefied
    console.log(this); // the button's DOM i clicked on
```

Comment: Gotta figure out why `$this` is coming back null... (it'd be helpful to know what got upgraded)

Comment: Well while you're looking for the problem, go ahead and declare `$this` with `var`.

Comment: Also it's unlikely anybody will know the answer unless somebody just happens to know what that "MMBBrowser" thing is.

Comment: It's a widget created with jquery.widget. So it's fully custom. That's why I thought it was a OOP "javascript" question. It seems indeed that I shall refer to BC break section of jquery-ui widget component.

Comment: As I recall, `this` in a widget method refers to the widget instance, and `this.element` refers to the element. As such, `$this` in your code does not hold a jQ collection that contains the element, rather it is a jQ collection that contains the widget instance. I believe you should be able to reference `this.options` to access the options you're after.

Comment: Also, your code is missing some curly braces.

Comment: Wish it was something that simple @JAAulde :( I've updated my question with some console.log output. Fixed curly braces too (only on stackoverflow)

Comment: @sf_tristanb I see...you're binding the `browser` method directly to an event. Your code does not show that, so I assumed it was a standard ui-widget method call.

Comment: I found the solution and edited my answer. How weird is that they remove the dot from the namespace....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#widget

> (#8801) Widgets used to store their instances in .data() using just
>   the plugin name as a key. The instances are now stored using the
>   widget namespace as well. For example, the dialog widget is now stored
>   in ui-dialog instead of dialog. See the 1.9 deprecation notice for
>   full details.

If the namespace is `MMB.MMBBrowser` then you can access it via `$(this).data('MMBMMBBrowser');`